# how to install libxml2 for c program in gcc mingw compiler in windows?

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have tried downloading the libxml,libxslt packages and adding the header files to the gcc compiler header files directory, but its not working.

Any one know how to install them properly?

Comment: Have you tried [following the compilation instructions](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html#Compilatio) or considered a [binary package](https://www.zlatkovic.com/projects/libxml/)?

Comment: Would you mind to give us more details, please? Which files did you download, where did you install them in which way, which "flavour" of MinGW is installed, what command lines did you use, ...? Please show us the source of your test program and the error messages you got. Unfortunately there is no thing like a crystal ball we could look into. ;-)

Comment: i have downloaded libxml,libxslt,xmlsec,iconv files which contains the header files for libxml2.
Added them to C:\gcc\lib\include\ where the rest of the header files exist.
but the gcc cant recognize them while including them in  program,
gcc `xml2-config --cflags --libs` test.c
it says xml2-config not found.
i think the header files are linked but some other error as i copied and pasted the header files instead of installing the libxml2 extension in original way.